# My second camera does not show my particle system

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, render, clipping

I have tried to use a second camera for my speed line particle system because that particles became invisible when an object comes to near to the screen. So I have a problem now my second camera does not show anything(when I change the occlusion to the ground, it also does not show any other layers.) How can I fix that? I put my screenshots of particle system and camera settings.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMK7I.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXnMp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErCGK.png)

Comment: can you add some more pictures of the differences between cameras and particle systems. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I handled the issue using particle camera as overlay to the main camera.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the material of the particle systems. Make sure that the shader of the material is Render Pipeline/Particles/Lit, if it is Unlit then change it to Lit.

Let me know if this does not help and why.

Comment: Actually it is normal when I choose that layer in my main camera, but does not work in the second one. I guess thats not the problem. Also when I choose a different layer in the second camera(like ground) that also does not shown when I play the game. I guess its something about the cameras and their relations but I couldn't figure it out.